# Show that any graph can be written as an edge disjoint union of its blocks

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Actually I am not very comfortable with using blocks, I understand the definition that it is a maximal $2$-connected graph, though.

**My attempt** Suppose not. Then there exists a maximal graph $G$ which cannot be written as an edge disjoint union of its blocks.

I cannot go further. I am not even sure why maximal exists, because the number of vertices of $G$ are not predetermined here. I am not even sure how can we write complete graph in such a fashion.

Please help

Comment: What is meaning of 2-connected? Also do you mean more specifically maximal 2-connected *subgraphs* of the starting graph? BTW by definition a graph has a finite number of vertices, though that may be a large number.

Comment: 2-connected graph means that we need to remove at least two vertices to disconnect the graph.

Comment: @coffeemath, yes it has a finite number of vertices, but we can talk about maximal when there is a poset. The poset we usually consider is: We consider a base graph and then the subgraphs of that form an ordered set. Here, we don't have a base graph.

Comment: That is creating much confusion. I tried to prove it using this because I've seen this strategy of maximality being used in many graph theoretic proofs.

Answer (score 1):

I think we need maximality of the blocks rather than maximality of the graph here.

Assume there is a graph, which cannot be written as edge disjoint union of blocks, that is to say there are two *distinct* blocks $A,B$, which share a common edge $xy$. Without loss of generality(1) we can assume that $x$ has a neighbor $a$ in $A\setminus B$. As $y$ and $a$ lie in $A$ we can find an $ay$-path $p$ in $A$ avoiding $x$ and hence $xy$. But this means that $B \cup p \cup xa$ is a 2-connected subgraph strictly containing $B$, a contradiction.

(1) Take an edge $uv$ in the intersection and a vertex $w$ in $A\setminus B$. By connectivity we have a $vw$-path. Traveling along this path we find the first edge that leaves the intersection (it may go into $B\setminus A$ but that is fine: just swap the meaning of $A$ and $B$).

Comment: Another argument that needs to be made at some point is that every edge is actually contained in a block (because every edge by itself is a subgraph with no cut vertex, so it's contained in some maximal subgraph with no cut vertex).

Comment: @MishaLavrov right.

Comment: Can you please explain what are you proving in the last paragraph??

Comment: Also, can you please elaborate why is $B\cup p$ 2-connected??

Comment: The last paragraph is meant to justify the without loss of generality. For the second I indeed made a mistake. I need to consider $B\cup p\cup xa$... Then it is an application of the fact that attaching the two endpoints of a path to **distinct** vertices of a 2-connected graph yields a new 2-connected graph.

Answer (score 0):

A block of a graph G is a maximal connected subgraph of G that has no articulation point(cut-point or cut-vertex). If G itself is connected and has no cut-vertex, then G is a block.Two or more blocks of a graph can meet at a single vertex only, which must necessarily be an articulation point of the graph.Hence, any graph can be written as an edge disjoint union of its blocks, because of their maximality.
We can prove this by contradiction.
Suppose we surmise a graph G which cannot be represented as an edge-disjoint union of blocks. For simplicity, let us consider that there are two different blocks **X** and **Y** which have a common edge **uv**. Without loss of generality, we are at liberty to assume that **u** has an adjacent vertex **m** in **X**. And **v** and **m** are vertices in **X**, therefore, there exists a path(**P**) between **v** and **m** not containing **u**. Evidently, **P** does not contain the edge **uv**. Also a path can be represented as a union of unique edges(k2 graphs, which are by definition blocks). Let **S** be the set of edges, in **X**-**uv**-**um**-**P**. And thus G can be represented by **Y** ∪ **um** ∪ **P** ∪ **S** which can be intuitively viewed as a union of different edge-disjoint blocks, which is a contradiction.